# How to use "would imagine, say, think, etc. (that)…: used to give opinions that you are not certain about" properly?

Tags: word-usage

In [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would)

**would imagine, say, think, etc. (that)…** used to give opinions that you are not certain about

*I would imagine the job will take about two days.*

*I'd say he was about fifty.*

My question is that does "*I'd say he was about fifty.*"="*he could be about fifty.*" & "*I would imagine the job will take about two days.*"="The job could take about two days"?

Second, do you native say "*I would say he could be about fifty.*"? (I am not sure whether we should use "**could**" in "**he could be about fifty.**" or "**could**" is unnecessary.) I would think that way of saying is not idiomatic, but I am not sure.

Comment: I don't get this. You write *do you native say "I would say he could be about fifty."?*, but then yourself use exactly the same construction in your last sentence: ***I would think** that way of saying is not idiomatic*. Why would you suppose *I would **say*** might not be "idiomatic", if you're obviously happy to just write *I would **think*** without giving it a thought?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, because I am not sure whether we should use "could" in "he could be about fifty." or "could" is unnecessary.

Comment: You mean you're not sure about the "doubling-up" of uncertainty because it's *I **would** say he **could** be about 50?* But hedging and being non-commital is just part of normal English. Obviously ***about*** is deliberately imprecise, and we could pile any number of additional "obfuscations" in there (introduce the statement with ***I don't really know, but if pressed perhaps** I'd say...,* muddy the value ***50*** by switching to ***fiftyish***, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentences you give have similar meanings.  There is a slight difference, though, and that is a difference in how much certainty the speaker has about the possibility.

"Would imagine" and related phrases emphasize that you are making your best guess, but you recognize that it is only a guess, and that you might be wrong.

> The job could take about two days.

To me, the speaker sounds like they're just offering two days as a *possibility*.  They are giving no opinion about how likely this is.  It might be very unlikely that it would actually take two days, and the speaker is just letting you know that it is possible.

> I would imagine the job will take about two days.

Here, the speaker is giving their opinion.  They think it is *likely* that the job will take about two days.  They might be wrong, but they are using what they know to make their best guess.

To your second question,

> I would say he could be about fifty.

This sounds slightly redundant to me, but not wrong.  I could imagine a native speaker saying it.  But the addition of "could" adds more uncertainty to the statement.  The speaker is making a guess, but they are quite unsure about how accurate their guess is.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd say he was about fifty.
>   He could be about fifty.

The principal difference between these two sentences is that the first is clearly a statement of the speaker's opinion and the second is a statement of probability. Could is defined in the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could) to imply **slight or uncertain possibility**

The first is regularly used exactly like this. The second can be used on its own to express a low probability, but it is more often used about the less probable of two options. For example,

> He looks about 40, but he could be as old as 50.
>  
>   It will probably take a couple of days, but it could take as long as a week.

Regarding the second part of your question:

> I would say he could be about fifty.

This sound rather strange, because **could** implies a low probability, so this sentence suggests that the speaker's best guess about something is improbable.

Comment: When do we use "I'd say he WAS about fifty". I think if I see someone now, i want to make a guess, It should be " I'd say he IS about fifty."

Comment: @LEHANH good question. We probably use the past because we want to make it match the tense of "would". Compare "I say he **is** about fifty" with "I **would** say he **was** about fifty".  See this Ngram graph, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=i+would+say+he+is%2C+I+would+say+he+was%2C+I%27d+say+he+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 which shows that "I would say he his..." is not used.

Comment: If so, when I make a guess about something in the present, the tense after "I would say" must be in the past tense. Right? But I just found an example in Longman dictionary with the present tense after "I would think" :  Is there a chance Chrysler might buy Fiat? I would think there IS essentially zero chance of that happening.

Comment: @LEHANH that's somewhat different because you are talking about a *future* possibility: will Chrysler buy Fiat at some time in the future?. That text sounds like spoken English- perhaps a TV news report. It sounds made up on the spot, and therefore not necessarily well thought out. Here are the figures for "I would think there is/was" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=i+would+say+there+is%2CI+would+say+there+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: That text sounds like spoken English=> if so what is the right way to say that sentence

Comment: @LEHANH replacing IS by WAS would be OK for speech.  In formal written English, you would probably wouldn't start with the rhetorical question: you would more likely see something clearer and more concise, for example "In my opinion, Chrysler will not buy Fiat".

Comment: You said this sentence is correct: "I would say he was about fifty". How about I would think: "I would think he WAS about fifty". "I would think" and "I would say" both are used to  give my opinion.

Comment: @LEHANH Yes, "I would think..." can fit the same pattern, though this NGram graph https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+say+that%2CI+would+think+that%2C+I+think+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 shows that "I would say" is very much more common.  Note that "I think that..." is very much more common than both, and I would not use **was** in that case: "I think he **is** about fifty"

Comment: When giving an opinion on the present thing, with “I would say” , I can use simple past for an opinion on the present, but with “I would think”, only simple present is correct. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH In my previous comment, I said that "I would think" can fit the same pattern, ie you would use simple past to match **would**.  "only simple present is correct" is true only if **would** is omitted , regardless of whether the main verb is think or say.

Comment: I would think/say he WAS about fifty. This version is the most common. Do you think that some people still use present tense : I would think/say he IS about fifty. Is using the present tense consider wrong in daily life?

Comment: @LEHANH you can easily check that for yourself. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+say+he+is%2C+would+say+he+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3